# Input from List (Python)

Tags: python, function, input

I have a parameter list which is just inputs separated by commas.

Now that I have a non-empty list, `myList[]`, how do I turn the entries of L into a parameter list?

Example: if want

```
myList[0], myList[1], myList[2]..., myList[10]
```

How can I do that? Thank you! Is there anything similar to unpacking?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) with `*`.

```
f(*myList)
```

Comment: @Newbie I do not know why it should not work, sorry.

Comment: @Newbie As you can see [here](https://ideone.com/ieeEZR), this code should work. I have no clue about your issue.

Comment: @Newbie What do you mean by "parameter list which is just inputs separated by commas"? I hardly understand.